# How to add an item to ComboBoxEdit?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a small problem with `ComboBoxEdit` (`DevExpress.XtraEditors`).  I cannot add a value or set `SelectedIndex` for my `ComboBoxExit`.

```
 ComboBoxEdit combo = new ComboBoxEdit();
 ComboBoxItemCollection coll = combo.Properties.Items;

 coll.BeginUpdate();

 try 
 {
    coll.Add(new PersonInfo("Sven", "Petersen"));
    coll.Add(new PersonInfo("Cheryl", "Saylor"));
    coll.Add(new PersonInfo("Dirk", "Luchte"));
 }
 finally 
 {
    coll.EndUpdate();
 }

 combo.SelectedIndex = -1; Comboboxedit1.Properties.Items.Add(combo);
```

It does not work and just adds shows this:

[image]

Comment: What do you expect this code to do exactly ?

Comment: I just want to know about it. 
More than a little is I want know how to set selectedIndex for comboboxedit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WIth this line :

`Comboboxedit1.Properties.Items.Add(combo);`

You are adding the ComboBox object inside itself. `ComboBoxEdit` ToString() method returns the name you are seeing in your screenshot.

So, remove this line.

Your code in taken from the official [DevExpress documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsComboBoxEdittopic) (except the line above that you should remove), and works fine : items are indeed added.

However, setting the `SelectedIndex` property to -1 doesn't select anything, as the documentation states :

> The BaseListBoxControl.SelectedIndex property is set to -1 for
>   demonstrative purposes (the property is set to -1 by default). This
>   ensures that no item is currently selected in the combo box.

You can do :

```
combo.SelectedIndex = 0;  // Select Sven
```

Or

```
combo.SelectedIndex = 1;  // Select Cheryl
```

Or

```
combo.SelectedIndex = 2;  // Select Dirk
```

Comment: What did you change to your code ? Which items do you see ? It works for me. Give stack trace instead of a screenshot (btw no code modification that I suggest can trigger a NullReference exception)

Comment: bro, thank you very much. I have done it. Thank again!

Answer (score -1):

Use some like this:

```
try
{
    ComboBoxEdit combo = new ComboBoxEdit();

    combo.Properties.Items.Add("Sven, Petersen");
    combo.Properties.Items.Add("Cheryl, Saylor");
    combo.Properties.Items.Add("Dirk, Luchte");
}
```

Will work fine!
No complication, no inovation, simple like need be!