# ComboBoxEdit' does not contain a definition for 'Items'

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am trying to link ComboboxEdit with Database values.But while writing the code my VS cant find the element Item :

```
magazin.Items.Add(s);
```

And it gives me this error :

> ComboBoxEdit' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no 'Items'
>   extension method that accepts a first argument of type  'ComboBoxEdit'
>   was found(is a directive using an assembly reference missing?

Here is my code :

```
static string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnxString"].ConnectionString;

public void fillCombo()
{
    ArticleDAL a = new ArticleDAL();

    string query = "select * from tbl_magazin;";
    SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(conString);
    SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand(query, cnx);
    SqlDataReader r;
    try
    {
        cnx.Open();
        r = c.ExecuteReader();
        while (r.Read())
        {
            string s = r["libelle"].ToString();
            magazin.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {}
    finally
    { }
}
```

Comment: [How to add an item to ComboBoxEdit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093133/how-to-add-an-item-to-comboboxedit)

Comment: is there a `magazin.properties.items.add()`? Just curious as I was reading [this](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.ComboBoxEdit.class) and they create a comboboxitem collection but I also saw that the collection was equal to `combo.Properties.Items`

Comment: Yeees it did !! the solution is `magazin.properties.items.add() `  Thank you  !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was suggested in comments The solution is using :

`comboBoxEdit.properties.items.add()`

instead of

`comboBoxEdit.Items.Add(s);`